# missing script error during the initialization of a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

> node ./postinstall.js

- react-scripts@4.0.3
- react@17.0.2
- react-dom@17.0.2
  added 1922 packages from 732 contributors and audited 1925 packages in 1282.186s

135 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.

**C:\Windows\System32\react-app> npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start**

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ObiTech ict Solution\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-05T21_07_44_609Z-debug.log

I got the error above while trying to initiate a new React App

Comment: What is the command you ran t create the react app?

Comment: create-react-app react-app (to create)                npm start (to initialize)

Comment: After creating the app you need to cd into the app folder by running `cd react-app` and then run `npm run start`.

Comment: I just did that now and I still got the same response

Comment: Can you post the content of your `package.json`?

Comment: "name": "reactapp1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

My package.json was missing the start script

The content of the package.json file looks like:

```
   {
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start", 
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  }
}
```